# Magento 1.9.1.0 to 2.2.3 Migration mapping error

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate the settings from a 1.9.1.0 install to a 2.2.3 install however I'm getting the following error with debugging enabled:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xH9gn8v.png]

I thought it was due to having settings.xml.dist still as .dist in the directory I change that to settings.xml and I then get a slightly different error message:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dBnkOEV.png]

Has anyone had this problem before or any ideas on how I can go about debugging this?

Thanks

Comment: Use https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro/ plugin its batter then default migration tool.

Answer (score 0):

When running the migration you give the path to a **config.xml** file. There you basically configure the parameters of your migration.

In the first case the following node contained an invalid value (e.g non-existing file or a file without enough permissions or simply a invalid map file)

```
<config><options><map_file>value</map_file></options></config>
```

The second time around you changed the **settings.xml.dist** file name but in your config the corresponding node still kept the previous value e.g

```
<settings_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
```

I suggest you read the docs a few times before running a migration.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/bk-migration-guide.html